# How to checkout from existing branch to new branch in Android Studio [Github]

Tags: android-studio, github

I have two computers in which the first computer has only one branch "master" and in the second computer i created another branch named as "demo". Now in the first computer how do i checkout from "master" branch and enter into the "demo" branch.